# Modern reference for a theorem by Bott on the Dolbeault cohomology of compact homogeneous manifolds

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, complex-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces, lie-algebra-cohomology

I am looking for a modern, maybe shorter or even easier, reference for Theorem II of *Homogeneous vector bundles* (R. Bott, Annals of mathematics, 1957). This is a theorem where the Dolbeault cohomology of a class of compact complex homogeneous manifolds is described in terms of the Lie algebras of the groups that define the homogeneous manifold.

I am trying to understand the proof of the mentioned theorem, but I am having a hard time understanding many aspects of Bott's approach. Now I am wondering if I can find a modern textbook with this result. Any recommendation will be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I sent you my few pages of notes on Bott's proof by email. The proof for flag varieties is in Cap and Slovak, Parabolic Geometries I, and lots of other places.

Comment: Dear @BenMcKay, thank you very much for your notes. They will surely help me understand Bott's proof.